# How to prevent div from moving when resizing window?

Tags: html, css, image, window-resize

fairly new to CSS and HTML here. I have a few questions:

currently trying to replicate [this website](https://projects.invisionapp.com/share/X575YEGVU#/screens/155416515), and whenever I resize my window so the width is smaller than my header image (1000px), one of the div starts to move as it tries to stay in the center. Basically I would like to keep all of the text content aligned vertically no matter no big the window size is.

Another question is how do I resize the content of `.quote::before`. I tried defining `width` and `height`, but no success.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2dmx9an3/) so you can check out the code.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

To awnser your first question,
you need to remove

`padding-left` and `padding-right` property from your `.main` rule.

```css
.main {
  width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 45px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
  color: #222;
}
```

I let you try this without `padding-left` and `padding-right`

To awnser your another question,
I guess you should use `media queries`
I let you an example

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 598px) {
  .quote {
    margin: 0 26px;
    width: unset;
  }
}
```